# functional tests admin section rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I have a question concerning a functional test in rails.

For the front section, the actions are *only index and show*

```
#app/controller/themes_controller_rb
class ThemesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @themes = Theme.active
  end

  def show
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

and the test

```
#test/integration/theme_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class ThemesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @theme = create(:theme)
  end

  test "should assign variable on index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:themes)
  end


  test "should show a theme" do
    get :show, {'id' => @theme}
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:theme)
  end

end
```

**No problem so far**

For the admin section, all the CRUD actions exists so again *index and show*

```
#app/controllers/admin/themes_controller.rb
class Admin::ThemesController < Admin::AdminController

  layout 'admin/admin'
  before_action :admin_user

  def index
    @themes = Theme.all
  end

  def show
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

and the tests are the same

```
#test/controllers/admin/theme_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'


    class Admin::ThemesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      def setup
        @theme = create(:theme)
      end

      test "should assign variable on index" do
        get :index
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil assigns(:themes)
      end


      test "should show a theme" do
        get :show, {'id' => @theme}
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil assigns(:theme)
      end

    end
```

but for those latest tests, I have a 302 response instead of succes

```
 FAIL["test_should_assign_variable_on_index", Admin::ThemesControllerTest, 2016-03-16 06:50:16 +0000]
 test_should_assign_variable_on_index#Admin::ThemesControllerTest (1458111016.61s)
        Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>
        test/controllers/admin/themes_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ThemesControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_show_a_theme", Admin::ThemesControllerTest, 2016-03-16 06:50:16 +0000]
 test_should_show_a_theme#Admin::ThemesControllerTest (1458111016.62s)
        Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>
        test/controllers/admin/themes_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:ThemesControllerTest>'
```

What do I do wrong ? Thanks for help :)

Comment: It would help to know what your `before_action :admin_user` is doing. If it is checking that a user is an admin, it's possible that you did not specify the user properly in your test.

Comment: Yes of course, that's the problem. So obvious I did'nt even see it. Thanks :)